# Facebook Graph API "{video_id}/video-insights" returning an empty "data'' array

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to the receive statistics such as the views, comments, shares, and reactions from a public video on my Facebook profile using the Facebook graph api.

I am trying to use the endpoint `{video_id}/video_insights` but this just returns an empty array `{data: Array(0)}` My scope is `read_insights,user_videos`

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '{app_id}',
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v3.3'
    });
    FB.login(response => {
        if (response.authResponse){
            let token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            let scope = response.authResponse.grantedScopes;
            FB.api('{video_id}/video_insights', response => {
                console.log(token);
                console.log(scope);
                console.log(response);
            })
        }
    },{scope: 'read_insights,user_videos', return_scopes: true});
}
```

This is what shows up in the console:

```
token = {access_token}
scope = 'user_videos,read_insights,public_profile'
response = {data: Array(0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no insights for user profiles, they are only available for Pages - and videos posted to Pages. You would also need the `manage_pages` permission in addition, to get a Page Token.

About user videos in general: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_videos

> This permission is restricted to a limited set of partners and usage
>   requires prior approval by Facebook.

Same for `user_photos`, as you can read on the same page.

Comment: Okay, but why does the endpoint me/videos or me/photos also return an empty array. Some endpoints return data back like the me/likes endpoint

Comment: i have updated my answer for that. did not know that either, but it seems to be restricted now.

Comment: I looked at the form for the app review. It seems silly I have to go through all that just to test things out, even going far as a screencast?! I am the admin of the app and using the same profile to auth. I even tried creating a test copy.

Comment: go through what exactly? "restricted to a limited set of partners" does not sound like you can get the permissions, even with review. short answer: it´s not possible.

Comment: My conclusion is that the graph api is not for people who just want to make a small project just to show to couple friends or to learn about javascript and apis. It's for businesses to create full scale apps. This is the process you have to through [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit)

Comment: that´s definitely true, yeah. if you want to learn javascript and apis, there are much better options anyway.